# If I "assign" someone a task, what is the correct verb for "unassigning" them?

Tags: verbs, antonyms

I am developing some software where users are assigned tasks. They will see a date and time for when they were assigned to the task, but if they were later removed from the task, there will be a date and time for that also.

```
01/02/14 - Assigned

03/02/14 - Unassigned
```

I'm pretty sure unassigned isn't correct. I suppose the task itself could be in a state of being unassigned, but the user wasn't "unassigned" from it.

Notes:

1. I don't want to use the word "removed", as I don't think it conveys the correct meaning and also sounds too harsh.
2. I would like to avoid using a word your average person would never have heard of, as this isn't very user-friendly from a software point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem... how is unassigned incorrect? If a user is assigned to work on task A and then task A was taken from them, then they were unassigned from task A. They once had an assignment, but they no longer have that assignment, therefore they are unassigned. Similarly, if task B is an open project that needs a user to work on it, then task B is an unassigned project until it gets a user, when it is assigned. I'd suggest (if the user is the one seeing "assigned/unassigned") you tell them what they were assigned to/unassigned from rather than changing the wording.

Comment: Withdraw someone from a task.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"revoked", "withdrawn", "retracted", or simply "reassigned"

Comment: "revoked" or "withrdawn" don't really seem very clear on their own.  I think "unassigned" is a more intuitive approach, otherwise "assignment revoked" is clear.  Creating new verbs isn't really something to be frowned upon.  For example texted, messaged.  If it starts to get used a lot, then it becomes a legitimate word.  So just use what's clear and makes sense.  Nobody's going to say "I don't know how to use this software, unassign isn't a word" right?

Comment: @JessePepper While I agree that this would still be understandable, the problem with using "unassign" as a verb in this instance, is that "unassigned" already exists as an adjective which describes the current state and has a different meaning than what the OP was after (he wanted a "de-assign" rather than an "un-assign").

Comment: @msam how do you know that?  Is it from communication outside of stack echange?

Comment: @JessePepper from the question: "...but if they were later removed from the task...". "Task unassigned" means it is not currently assigned to anyone (Noun + adjective, dictionary definitions). To get the required meaning "removed from the task" relative to the "user", "unassigned" would have to be a verb (which would really mean "de-assigned" as in my previous comment - see dictionary definitions of "un-" and "de-" prefixes for clarification). You are of course free to use "unassign" as a verb (I'm not one to frown upon incorrect use of latin prefixes), but it can be a source of confusion.

Comment: +1 for unassigning! Language is flexible :)